# strcpy() is not copying properly c++

Tags: c++, strcpy, strcat

Recently I made a program, it has a character array `board[8][8][2];`

It is basically meant to be a 8X8 board which can store '2' lettered strings. I am not providing the complete code.

But here is the problem.

```
for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    strcpy(board[1][j], P[j].sym);
}

cout << board[1][1] << endl;
```

Here `P[1].sym="P1"` and `P[0].sym="P0"` and `P[2].sym="P2"`

Therefore `P[j].sym` is basically a two letter string and `board[1][j]` should also be a two letter string.

But the output for

```
cout << board[1][1] << endl;
```

is given as `P1P2P3P4P5P6P7`

and the output for

```
cout << board[1][0] << endl;
```

is given as `P0P1P2P3P4P5P6P7`

For

```
cout << board[1][5] << endl;
```

`P5P6P7` is the output.

To remove any doubt the whole `board[8][8][[2]` is already initialised
and all of `P[j].sym` are already initialised.

If it helps here is the code for the initialisation of `P`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
   char board[8][8][2];
   char *****possibilities;
 };

class Pawn : virtual public Game {
 public:
     char sym[2];
     int possiblec[4][2];
     Pawn() { }

     Pawn(int i) {
         char a[2];
         a[0] = 'P';
         a[1] = (char)(i + 48);
         strcpy(sym, a);
     }
};
```

And here somewhere else in the program I did

```
    Pawn P[8];
```

It calls the constructor and then later on I called the parameterised contructor explicitly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    P[i] = i;
}
```

After this I checked for different values of `P[j].sym` and all of them return the perfect values I wanted.

But not when I'm using `strcpy()` What is the problem here. This program is just a practice program to get a hang of it.

Comment: to store a 2 letter string, you need at least a 3 char capacity

Comment: it may not be a good question but help would be appreciated. As I need to learn my mistakes. Anyone patient enough can explain me my mistake.

Comment: vals how does that effect what i store in  board. and also board has a limit of only 2 characters how does it store so many?

Comment: `board[8][8][2]` should be `board[8][8][3]`, you need to make room for the null string terminator character `\0`.

Comment: A string needs to be null terminated. As I said, to store 2 chars in a string, you need space for 2 char and for the terminator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Character arrays in C++ ( and C ) are terminated with a Null character (`'\0'` ) . So, even if you need to store just two characters in your string, you must have an extra space to store the Null character.

A character array which does not terminate with a Null character can lead to a lot of other problems. It is a wrong practice.

If your character array does not terminate with a Null character, you will get a lot of problems when you call functions such as `strcpy()` , `strcat()` , etc...

So, you should change

```
char board[8][8][2]
```

to

```
char board[8][8][3]
```

And if you have any other strings just like this one, then leave one extra space in them as well.

The reason your code behaved as such is because you got lucky.

Functions such as `strcpy()` , `strcat()`  all continue to copy ( or append ) until they encounter a Null Character ( which is numerically equal to zero ). So, it continues to do so until the Null character is encountered. But if there is no Null character, then you will most probably get Undefined Behavior. In your case, you just got lucky.

I will show you a brief working of `strcpy()` ( from [here](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=547) )

```
char * strcpy(char p, const char * q) {
while (*p++=*q++);
//there's also a return p; statement at the end
}
```

That is the function.

the while loop executes until it encounters false, and the equivalent for false is `0`. So, when it encounters a Null character ( which is also numerically equal to `0` ), the while loop terminates and the copying is complete, and the function ends. So, if there is no Null character at the end, it will give you undefined Behavior.

You can refer [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) for more info about them

Answer (score 3):

You should always reserve one *extra character* because strings in C and C++ are `null terminated`, which that they need one extra character to sign the end of the string.

So, please, change

```
board[8][8][2]
```

to

```
board[8][8][3]
```

as well as `sym[2]` to `sym[3]`, `a[2]` to `a[3]` (generally add one to the length of all strings) and try again.

By looking at the manual pages for `strcpy`:

> Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by
>   destination, including the terminating null character (and stopping at
>   that point).

This means that that function will stop only when it encounters the null character. That's why it would fail if there wasn't any present. But, by setting one character at a time, there's obviously no such problem visible (it will become visible later on, if you try to execute a function that stops only when it encounters a null character and there are plenty of them).

Comment: Oh Thanks , I did not know that not having enough space would cause the program to behave weirdly.... yes it was weird that it printed all..... any reasons why the program behaved like that?

Comment: Yes, you're obviously right. You should increase the length of all strings by one to have one more space for that `null character`,

Answer (score 2):

Strings are null ('\0') terminated in C++.  When you pass in an character array to printf it stops printing at the null character.  I'm guessing the only reason it stopped printing at P7 is because you got lucky and the next memory location happens to be storing Null.  You need to make your char arrays at least 1 character longer than the string you want to store.